# How to display data from a SQL Server database table to a combo box in Wpf?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox

I'd like to display data from a SQL Server database table to a combo box in Wpf/C#.

Currently I have a table `Lookup_Type` that contains two columns, `SectorNumber` and `Description`.

Suppose the data stored in this table are:

```
SectorNumber   Description
---------------------------
     01        Antitrust
     02        Civil Rights
     03        Criminal
     04        Tax
     ...
```

I have a text block and a combo box in my MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<Textblock Text="Type of Justice Agencies: " Name="TypeTextBlock" ... />
<Combobox Name="TypeComboBox" 
          Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" 
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
          ... />
```

How to display data from a SQL Server database table to a combo box in C#?

I'd like the combo box item to read like `01, Antitrust`, `02, Civil Rights`, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Plenty of examples out there.  Did you look or try anything?

Comment: what did you try exactly.. ? do a google search on how to bind a ComboBox from Sql Server

Comment: Why are you try to be condescending on a Q-and-A website? Yes I did that.

Comment: Then you would have found tons of examples so code wise show us what you have tried..? this site is not here to answer your very broad question if you were to show some effort / code and where you are having issues.. then we could help.

Comment: Do you know how to connect to a database?, how to prepare a sql statement?, how to execute such statement and receive the database output? (In other words do you know how to work with the ADO.NET libraries?) There is a lot to explain here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900062/c-sharp-fill-combo-box-from-sql-datatable found this in less than 1 sec come on now @Hank

Comment: I am connecting to the SQL server database and I tried a few LINQ statements to display data on a datagrid using ado.net entity items. That part is taken care of. I see there are two existing questions on that on this site.

Comment: I see that you still are not getting the picture.. show your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960283/how-to-get-data-from-sql-database-to-store-in-combo-box-c-sharp

Comment: @MethodMan, I read that QandA as well. I am trying to add combo box items in wpf. I will update my questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494634/fill-combobox-from-database

Comment: You can down vote as much as you can. I don't care.

Answer (score 2):

```
Here example:      

var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "01, Antitrust");
dict.Add(2, "02, Civil Rights");
dict.Add(3, "03, Criminal");
dict.Add(4, "04, Tax");
myCombobox.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
myCombobox.DisplayMember = "Value";
myCombobox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to extract this data  from the database table not hard coding it. Besides, "01, Antitrust" should be the item displayed

Comment: Change int to string... new Dictionary<int, string>(); --> new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: That's fine. Everything helps. Thanks Valentin.